# Getting The SUM() of COUNT()

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way in mysql to achieve

```
SELECT COUNT( SUM(field2) ) FROM TABLE WHERE field1='value' GROUP BY field2
```

Returning one row with the total sum of the counted field 2.

Field 1 && Field 2 are both not unique.

If there is a need for more info , just let me know.

**Edit :** 
I was not thinking clear.
I need the COUNT of The COUNT.

so all the counted values from field 2.
this can be achieved by getting the number of rows , but I chose for this :

```
SELECT COUNT( first_count ) total_count FROM 
( SELECT COUNT( field2 ) as first_count FROM TABLE
  WHERE field1='value' GROUP BY field2 )t1
```

Or is there a faster query?

Cheers !

Comment: `GROUPED BY` sounds nice, but it's not correct :)

Comment: SUM(field2) returns 1 value per field2, can you clarify what you want a count of?

Comment: Can you post some sample input and expected output?

Comment: Sample data and expected results is probably the best way to describe what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your update

```
SELECT COUNT( first_count ) total_count FROM 
( 
  SELECT COUNT( field2 ) as first_count FROM TABLE
  WHERE field1='value' GROUP BY field2 )t1
)
```

Is a count of the COUNTs for each field2, which is the same as a count of unique field2s;

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field2) FROM TABLE WHERE field1='value'
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you mean:

```
SELECT field2
     , field2 * COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE
WHERE field1 = 'value'
GROUP BY field2
```

Also:

There is no `GROUPED BY`. There is: `GROUP BY`

---

After your update and clarification, I think what your query shows is the same with:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT field2 ) AS total_count
FROM TABLE
WHERE field1 = 'value'
```